# What do i do if my folder and controller use the same name?

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I have a vendor folder created by composer on my codeigniter project and i also have a vendor controller, so when i load `localhost/my_project/vendor`  it will open the composer folder instead but when i use `localhost/my_project/index.php/vendor` it loads the controller please any possible way of solving this issue.
 When i use  `localhost/my_project/admin` it works perfectly incase you thinking i didn't use the default .htaccess file.

```
if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
  exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Vendor extends CI_Controller
{


    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();
        $this->load->library('paypal');
        $this->load->library('twoCheckout_Lib');
        $this->load->library('vouguepay');
        /*cache control*/
        $this->output->set_header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
        $this->output->set_header('Pragma: no-cache');
        //$this->crud_model->ip_data();
        $vendor_system = $this->db->get_where('general_settings', array('type' => 'vendor_system'))->row()->value;
        if ($vendor_system !== 'ok') {
            redirect(base_url(), 'refresh');
        }
    }

    /* index of the vendor. Default: Dashboard; On No Login Session: Back to login page. */
    public function index()
    {
        if ($this->session->userdata('vendor_login') == 'yes') {
            $page_data['page_name'] = "dashboard";
            $this->load->view('back/index', $page_data);
        } else {
            $page_data['control'] = "vendor";
            $this->load->view('back/login', $page_data);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm not too familiar with codeigniter, but having your Composer vendor directory underneath your document root doesn't sound like the best idea

Comment: Adding to @iainn: The Composer /vendor/ directory can be stored outside the web-root, e.g. (var/www/vendor/… & /var/www/htdocs/index.php) which will result in a web-root that you can overlook at a first glance and no PHP in /vendor/ can be executed through a direct request.

Answer (score 0):

You should to set right settings for your web server. You may setup rewrite rules as in example below.
if you are using apache:

```
<LocationMatch "^/vendor">
  RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</LocationMatch>
```

if you are using nginx:

```
location /vendor {
  rewrite (.*) /index.php last;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Codeigniter uses the same Apache mod_rewrite snippet as so many applications:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Those both conditions first check if there is a file (`-f`) or directory (`-d`) with the requested name. And only if no such file or directory exists, the RewriteRule will take effect. Since you already have a directory "vendor" you have to set an exception for that directories name before the other rewrite:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^vendor/.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Comment: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^vendor/.* is how to set the exception right